# Sending multiline text as a single message in whatsapp using python

Tags: python-3.x, whatsapp

I want to send multi-line text as a single message in whatsapp. I have the code below. But its sending as 2 separate messages. Please help me to sort this.

```py
url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('c:/users/user/desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title = '{}']".format("Tom"))
user.click()

input_msg = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = '_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text']")
input_msg.click()
input_msg.send_keys("Your are the winner!!!\nContact 12345 for assistance" + Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: I'd guess it's because `\n` becomes an Enter key press, what if you explicitly send Alt+Enter there?

Comment: Sorry, i dont get that point. How to do that?

Comment: I'd guess similarly to how you use `Keys.ENTER`, but you should check the docs for the tools you're using as to how to add modifier keys.

Comment: My string also have variables...”You are the winner” + name+ “Contact 12345 for assistance”

Comment: I tried various keys but its being sent as 2 separate messages only

Comment: What happens when you send a carriage return (CR) instead of a line feed (LF)? That would be a `\r` instead of `\n`. You could even try a `\r\n`, although I strongly suspect that will send the message anyway.

Comment: Try a couple of control characters.

Comment: ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform() fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Because `"\n"` is equivalent to the enter key, WhatsApp Web will do "enter" instead of "shift+enter".

You should do this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

input_msg.send_keys("Your are the winner!!!"+ Keys.SHIFT + Keys.Enter +"Contact 12345 for assistance" + Keys.ENTER)
```